# bad argument #3 to 'Value' (string expected, got Object) - How do I fix this?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have looked at a number of other questions and their answers but I still don't seem to be able to fix this error message. I am writing a script which allows one player to change the face of another player. Due to the new ROBLOX update it is FE compatible therefore I will put both the Local Script and Server Script below even though the error is in the Server Script.

**Local Script:**

```
plr = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.NameInput.Text

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.RemoteEvent:FireServer(plr)
end)
```

**Server Script:**

```
faceid = script.Parent.FaceID.Value

script.Parent.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    script.Parent.PName.Value = plr
    local plrname = script.Parent.PName.Value
    print (plrname)
    game.Players[script.Parent.PName.Value].Character.Face.Texture = faceid
end)
```

**Hierarchy:**
[This is the image of the hierarch of the GUI I am creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMqFd.png)

**Error Message:** [This is the image of the error I am receiving when I press the 'Test Face' button which is named 'One' in the explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4nLi.png)

The server script is a bit messy as I have tried a few different ways to get around this error so if you think I could change anything or add/remove anything I would appreciate feedback on that. However, the main issue currently is the error I am getting on Line 4. There was also a previous error on Line 7 which said 'bad argument #2 to '?' (string expected, got Object)', but I would like to solve this issue first. Help with the scripts in general would be appreciated if deemed necessary by the people who attempt to help me.

Thank you in advance,
Rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using, `plr` you should get the name of the plr by using `plr.Name`.This way, you'll be telling the system the name of the player instead of getting the object.

```
faceid = script.Parent.FaceID.Value

script.Parent.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    script.Parent.PName.Value = plr.Name -- edit was here
    local plrname = script.Parent.PName.Value
    print (plrname)
    game.Players[script.Parent.PName.Value].Character.Face.Texture = faceid
end)
```